# Docking c# winforms of multiple instances of the same appliction

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# .net 2.0 winforms application which consists basically of one form A.

I am building another form B with a tabcontrol on it.
From the form B, I would like to be able to create one or more instances of this application.
Each form A I would like to be placed on tabpages on form B's tabcontrol.

Each instance is a different process that is running on a separated folder.

How could I achieve this?

Another way to put this is, how I could dock a form from another running instance into the current application instance's form.

Comment: Don't.  Have project B reference project A so you can just create these A form instances in your B project.  Works *much* better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TabbedMDIChildForms.aspx). It is what you are searching for.

Comment: This would be ok if I would like to dock forms from the same application instance. What I would like to achieve, is to dock forms from different instances of the same application, e.g. executables of the same application that run as different processes.

Comment: Sorry, read your question to fast - but combine with http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setparent and finwindow, you can set the other instance windows to yours

Comment: I achieved this with using SetParent & FindWindowEx. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to have to versions of your app.  One is the executable and the other is a component that you could add dynamically.  I have an app that I do this with tool controls.  Each tool represents a separate set of functionality that can be added to a workspace (tab) depending on the user's need for it.  For example, I have a tool for logging particular items that's called "logger" and a user can create a new instance of it which essentially adds it as a new tab in the main window.  Just a thought.  I think docking two running instances of the same application would have to be handled by Windows through the app docking interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control the source code for both of these applications then I don't think you can accomplish your objective.

If you DO control the source code, then I would recommend that you isolate the Form A functionality in a usercontrol in a separate library and reference this from the form in AppA and from the tab control in App B